# The tour page on Stack Exchange is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, stackexchange.com, tour

In the reputation part of [Stack Exchange tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour), the reputation required for some privileges are wrong.

```
1       Vote to close, reopen, or migrate questions
500     Edit other people's posts
1000    Access to moderation tools
```

I think these are wrong. The reputation required should be 2000, 3000 and 10000.

Comment: I think it's true for private beta sites where it's crucial users will be able to close the bad questions right away. :)

Answer (score 9):

A humble suggestion, as the reputation needed to gain privileges fluctuates several times in a site's life - one could just use an ellipsis to indicate that they *exist*:

> ...   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate questions
>
> ...   Edit other people's posts
>
> ...   Access to moderation tools

Or just show the concept of incremental privileges:

> ✓ Vote to close, reopen, or migrate questions
>
> ✓ Edit other people's posts
>
> _  Access to moderation tools

However, it's not something I'd consider a huge priority at the moment. That particular piece took quite a bit of time to put together, and while it's *theoretically* possible it could turn our privilege cake into a lie on some random site, I don't think it's very likely to occur.

Whether the *potential* confusion is worth the work of making the code different for *only* that copy of the page is up to the folks that have to implement it. Those are just ideas, so I put them somewhere more useful to folks than the confines of my noggin.

Answer (score 5):

Well, given that StackExchange.com is **not** a Q&A site, it doesn't have privileges.

The page is an illustration for how the Q&A network operates.

And you know? Different sites have different reputation requirements for the different privileges (most apparent when you compare sites in private beta vs public beta vs launched sites), so whatever is on that page is wrong when compared to a specific site.

---

I have updated the page to display an ellipsis (…) instead of any specific reputation (as @Tim suggested in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236929/140505)).

Comment: Think it's misleading as one might first visit the portal, see he can have those powers at 1 rep, join Stack Overflow and get upset it was a lie.

Comment: I didn't know that... But I think it should be changed to something else because it's misleading.

Comment: @yyt16384 - I have raised this internally, we may well change it.

Comment: would it not seem more... 'correct' to use the ticks (Tim's second suggestion)? The `...` doesn't seem right.... [stackexchange.com/tour doesn't have rep levels for the moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260777/260841)