# stackexchange.com/tour doesn't have rep levels for the moderation tools

Tags: feature-request, bug, stackexchange.com, tour

On https://stackexchange.com/tour:

> [image]

You can see the bottom section just has `...` as the 'Reputation'.

I *think* these may have been skipped because the rep level depends on what status the site is at (beta/graduated), but still... it looks empty and just wrong.

Please can *something* be added there?

Comment: tagged as bug+feature-request because I'm not completely sure why these aren't there, although I think my guess is right...

Comment: What could be put there?

Comment: Probably because it's different between beta sites and graduated sites, since this is the main portal, it better not confuse people too much. :)

Comment: Fun fact: it used to show the numbers, and [fixed as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236926/the-tour-page-on-stack-exchange-is-wrong)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmmm I'd rather have Tim Post's *second* suggestion with the ticks - the `...` doesn't seem right... does it to you??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yup, post a comment to him and/or Oded. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236926/the-tour-page-on-stack-exchange-is-wrong#comment850345_236928) :)